# Firebase crashlytics fails build after updating android gradle plugin to 7.0.2

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, crashlytics

I'm working on multi-flavor android app
After updating the Android Gradle plugin to the `7.0.2` version (from '4.1.1') to access a new variant API, I get the following error during the app build:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':app:injectCrashlyticsMappingFileIdRandstadAccDebug' (type 'InjectMappingFileIdTask').
- Type 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.gradle.tasks.InjectMappingFileIdTask' property 'mappingFileId' of mutable type 'org.gradle.api.provider.Property' is writable.

Reason: Properties of type 'org.gradle.api.provider.Property' are already mutable.

Possible solution: Remove the 'setMappingFileId' method.

Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#mutable_type_with_setter for more details about this problem.
- Type 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.gradle.tasks.InjectMappingFileIdTask' property 'resourceFile' of mutable type 'org.gradle.api.file.RegularFileProperty' is writable.

Reason: Properties of type 'org.gradle.api.file.RegularFileProperty' are already mutable.

Possible solution: Remove the 'setResourceFile' method.

Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#mutable_type_with_setter for more details about this problem.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.  Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

I'm using the latest version of firebase BOM 28.4.1.

Is there any walkaround for this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In my case, the fix was to update the crashlytics plugin to the current newest version: 2.7.1